# Remove root directory from filename in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want to split this line

```
/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh
```

to

```
/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh
```

Can I use sed or awk command for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove first directory components from path of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311956/remove-first-directory-components-from-path-of-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh' | sed  's@^/[^/]\+@@'
```

Explanatory words: using sed's replace function, we redefine the separator, which is commonly `/`, to `@`, saving us the escaping of slashes within the string. We anchor the regex at the beginning of line `^`, and replace the first slash, followed by any non-slash, with nothing, thus removing the first element of the path (not the root, btw).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need awk or sed , just try this

```
echo -n "/"; echo "/home/edwprod/abortive_visit/bin/abortive_proc_call.ksh" |cut -f3-6 -d/
```